# passing parameters in dynamically created link button click event

Tags: asp.net

My Problem is that i am creating dynamic link buttons in a dynamic cell. 
And from that im handling an event of link button

```
lnk.Click += new EventHandler(this.LinkButton_Click);            
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    //perform some logic
}
```

I want to do something on this dynamically created link button click event but for that I need to pass some parameters..
I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simlar question which may help you.

You can use coomand artuments and command name to solve your problem.

[create buttons dynamically to call method and pass in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840821/create-buttons-dynamically-to-call-method-and-pass-in-parameter)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simlar question which may help you. 
You can use coomand artuments and command name to solve your problem. 
create buttons dynamically to call method and pass in parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CommandArgument and CommandName properties. Set them on creation and retrieve them using lnk.CommandArgument or lnk.CommandName

Comment: but  i need to pass more thn 2 strings whenever that link button is created

Comment: you could separate them with a special caracter, like ':'. Simply use the Split() method when retreiving the values. Would that work for you?

Comment: yes i knw how to split that.but that wont work.because i will be using those strings in a sql query..moreover im confused on how to pass those strings on declaring the click event

Comment: You don't need to pass those strings in any specific way, they are available in the click event method. You need to set those value when dynamically creating the linkbutton. You sill then be able to use those variables in your sql query.